# Drupal get database configuration

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is there any function preserved to extract database configuration inside of my code, something like
`$db_user = drupal_get_dbuser();
$db_pass = drupal_get_dbpass();

...

...`

Comment: Why would you need that? Drupal already gives you connections and thin abstraction layer as seen on http://api.drupal.org/api/group/database

Comment: The reason I've been developing a module which should create database dumps on demand of an admin user.

Comment: You may also want to look at drush, wich has many command-line options for dumping and extracting databases, or -credentials. http://drush.ws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for this is:

```
<?php
  global $db_url;
  $creds =  parse_url($db_url);
  print $creds['user'];
  print $creds['pass'];
  var_dump($creds);
?>
```

More detailed info and edge-cases can be found by reading the code of http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_connect/6